# how can find multiple label using for loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to find multiple labels using a for loop, but I'm only finding the last label. Here is my code:

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    label.Name = "label" + i;
    label.Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30);
    label.TabIndex = i;
    label.Visible = true;
    //label[i].Name=
    label.Text = "jjgggg";


    this.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

I want all labels between 1 to 5 if I input 5.

Comment: Looks like you are `adding` labels rather than `finding` them...

Comment: Are you trying to find labels that are in a form you created with the WinForms designer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're repeatedly assigning to the properties of the same label. You need something like:

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name = "label" + i;
    label.Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30);
    label.TabIndex = i;
    label.Visible = true;
    label.Text = "jjgggg";

    this.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

You might also want to consider using an object initializer:

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label
    {
        Name = "label" + i,
        Location = new Point(100, 100 + i * 30),
        TabIndex = i,
        Visible = true,
        Text = "jjgggg"
    };

    this.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: @sumona: Well this code will create 5 labels, whereas before you didn't. Your question is currently pretty unclear though - you haven't even said what UI framework you're using. Please clarify your question, including the behaviour with my code.

Comment: I think you have missed the point, I expect the labels have been created by the hidden code the WinForms designer creates.

Comment: @Ian: It's possible that I've missed the point, as the question is extremely unclear... it doesn't look like it's "finding" anything - it's "setting" properties instead.